# Maze Generator using Recursive Division

Tags: java, recursion, maze

I took a class awhile ago and one of our assignments was trying to get a maze generated using recursive division.  Try as I might, I could never get the code to work properly.  Fast forward to several months later and I have been going through my old code to try to get it to work now on my own.  I have tried several different things with this code but when I keep trying to call the function recursively I could never get it to properly divide again.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  I can get the initial maze up but getting it to recursively divide into each quadrant is not working.  I've tried subtracting 'row' and 'col' variables by 1 and doing the recursive statement again but I just can't seem to get it to bite without an error appearing.  Any suggestions?  My code is below:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ser222_01_01_hw02_base
{

    //Seed for the random number generator
    static Random rand = new Random();

    //standard console size in characters.
    private static final int LEVEL_HEIGHT = 25;
    private static final int LEVEL_WIDTH = 80;

    private static final char ICON_WALL = '#';
    private static final char ICON_BLANK = ' ';

    /**
     * Returns a 2D array containing a statically created maze with dimentions
     * 80x24.
     *
     * @return 2D array containing a maze
     */
    private static char[][] makeMazeStatic()
    {
        //the following maze was generated with the recursive division method and then modified by hand.

        char level[][] =
        {
            {
                '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'
            },
            {
                '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'
            }
        };

        return level;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a random maze in a 2D array.
     *
     * @see
     * <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Recursive_division_method">Recursive_division_method</a>
     * @return 2D array containing a maze
     */
    private static char[][] makeMaze()
    {
        char level[][] = createBlankLevel();

        makeMazeRecursive(level, 1, 1, LEVEL_WIDTH - 2, LEVEL_HEIGHT - 2); //TODO: may need to change but probably not.

        return level;
    }

    /**
     * Creates an empty level of standard level height and width. Level will be
     * blank but bordered with wall characters.
     *
     * @return 2D array containing a maze
     */
    private static char[][] createBlankLevel()
    {
        char level[][] = new char[LEVEL_HEIGHT][LEVEL_WIDTH];

        //reset level to be entirely blank
        for (int y = 0; y < LEVEL_HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < LEVEL_WIDTH; x++)
            {
                level[y][x] = ' ';
            }
        }

        //top barrier
        for (int x = 0; x < LEVEL_WIDTH; x++)
        {
            level[0][x] = ICON_WALL;
        }

        //bottom barrier
        for (int x = 0; x < LEVEL_WIDTH; x++)
        {
            level[LEVEL_HEIGHT - 1][x] = ICON_WALL;
        }

        //left barrier
        for (int y = 0; y < LEVEL_HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            level[y][0] = ICON_WALL;
        }

        //left barrier
        for (int y = 0; y < LEVEL_HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            level[y][LEVEL_WIDTH - 1] = ICON_WALL;
        }

        return level;
    }

    //TODO: complete method.
    private static void makeMazeRecursive(char[][] level, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
    {

        //Create the row and column
        int row = rand.nextInt((endY - startY) + 1) + startY;
        int col = rand.nextInt((endX - startX) + 1) + startX;

        //Base Case: the maze is less than 3 x 3
        if ((row < 3) && (col < 3))
        {
            return;
        } else
        {

            //Generate a random row
            for (int y = startX; y <= endX; y++)
            {
                level[row][y] = ICON_WALL;
            }

            //Generate a random column
            for (int x = startY; x <= endY; x++)
            {
                level[x][col] = ICON_WALL;
            }

            //Generate 3 random doors
            int door1 = rand.nextInt((endX - col) + 1) + col;
            int door2 = rand.nextInt((col - startX) + 1) + startX;
            int door3 = rand.nextInt((endY - row) + 1) + row;
            //Generate the doors
            for (int y = startX; y <= endX; y++)
            {
                if (door1 == y)
                {
                    level[row][y] = ICON_BLANK;
                }
            }

            for (int y = startX; y <= endX; y++)
            {
                if (door2 == y)
                {
                    level[row][y] = ICON_BLANK;
                }
            }

            for (int x = startY; x <= endY; x++)
            {
                if (door3 == x)
                {
                    level[x][col] = ICON_BLANK;
                }
            }
        }

        //Recursive calls
        makeMazeRecursive(level, startX, startY, row - 1, col - 1);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a level in the console.
     *
     * @param level 2D array containing a maze
     */
    private static void drawLevel(char[][] level)
    {
        int y, x;

        for (y = 0; y < LEVEL_HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < LEVEL_WIDTH; x++)
            {
                System.out.print(level[y][x]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Entry point.
     *
     * @param args command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //show static maze (uncomment for sample output)
        //drawLevel(makeMazeStatic());
        //show recursive maze
        drawLevel(makeMaze());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Recursive_division_method) for graphic animation of how your recursive method could work:

[image: recursive maze]

Actually, your method creates 2 walls, one horizontal and one vertical, and 3 doors in those 2 walls, as shown in the article too.

Once you create 1 (or 2) walls, you end up with 2 (or 4) rooms, and your method must **call itself for each room**, with *2 (or 4) difference starting coordinates* and appropriate sizes.

Your method only **calls itself once**, with same starting coordinate (`startX`, `startY`). Re-think that part of your logic.

---

Also, method is declared as `makeMazeRecursive(level, startX, startY, endX, endY)`, but is called recursively with `makeMazeRecursive(level, startX, startY, row - 1, col - 1)`, i.e. you assign:

```
endX = row - 1
endY = col - 1
```

**`row` and `col` are flipped**.

Comment: Thanks!  I've gotten at least the upper-left quadrant done and now I'm figuring out how to store the original intersection so that I can get the rest of them done.  Once I get that I'll finally have it.  The x and y (rows and columns) have always been my downfall since day one on a two-dimension array

Comment: I think I got it now

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it now.  I changed up the code to get it to draw in all 4 quadrants but depending on where it adds the first two lines at it may never get a quadrant fully or filled at all.

'''private static void makeMazeRecursive(char[][] level, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
    {

```
    //Create the row and column
    int row = rand.nextInt((endY - startY) + 1) + startY;
    int col = rand.nextInt((endX - startX) + 1) + startX;

    //Base Case: the maze is less than 3 x 3
    if ((endX - startX) < 3 || (endY - startY) < 3)
    {

        return;

    } else
    {

        //Generate a random row
        for (int y = startX; y <= endX; y++)
        {
            level[row][y] = ICON_WALL;
        }

        //Generate a random column
        for (int x = startY; x <= endY; x++)
        {
            level[x][col] = ICON_WALL;
        }

        //Generate 3 random doors
        int door1 = rand.nextInt((endX - col) + 1) + col;
        int door2 = rand.nextInt((col - startX) + 1) + startX;
        int door3 = rand.nextInt((endY - row) + 1) + row;
        //Generate the doors
        for (int y = startX; y <= endX; y++)
        {
            if (door1 == y)
            {
                level[row][y] = ICON_BLANK;
            }
        }

        for (int y = startX; y <= endX; y++)
        {
            if (door2 == y)
            {
                level[row][y] = ICON_BLANK;
            }
        }

        for (int x = startY; x <= endY; x++)
        {
            if (door3 == x)
            {
                level[x][col] = ICON_BLANK;
            }
        }
    }

    //Find the intersection of the two lines
    for (int x = 0; x < level.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < level[x].length; y++)
        {
            if (x == row)
            {
                endY = x;
            }
            if (y == col)
            {
                endX = y;
            }
        }
    }

    //Call the method again for the upper-left quadrant
    makeMazeRecursive(level, startX, startY, endX, endY);

    //Reset the coordinates for the upper-right quadrant
    endX = LEVEL_WIDTH - 2;
    endY = row;

    //Call the method again for the upper-right quadrant
    makeMazeRecursive(level, startX, startY, endX, endY);

    //Reset the coordinates for the lower right quadrant
    endX = LEVEL_WIDTH - 2;
    endY = startY;

    //Call the method again for the lower-right quadrant
    makeMazeRecursive(level, startX, startY, endX, endY);

    //Reset the coordinates for the lower-left quadrant
    endX = startX;
    endY = col;

    //Call the method again for the lower-left quadrant
    makeMazeRecursive(level, startX, startY, endX, endY);
}'''
```

Thanks for all the help!